# MySQL: Return a row if all joint table row have the value true

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've two tables as following.

```
Table A
Column Id | Column Name
1         | Test 1
2         | Test 2
```

The relationship is

```
Table B
Column Id | Column Delivered | Column TableA_Id
1         | true             | 1
2         | true             | 1
3         | true             | 1
4         | true             | 1
5         | false            | 2
6         | true             | 2
7         | true             | 2
```

What I want is to return for example for table A the record with id 1 which has a relationship with table B where all the values on table B column Delivered as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select tablea_id
from b
group by tablea_id
having sum( delivered <> 'true' ) = 0;
```

This doesn't use table a.  If you want all the columns there, you can also use;

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b 
                  where b.tablea_id = a.id and b.delivered <> 'true'
                 );
```

The one difference with this query is that it will also return rows in `a` that have no rows in `b` at all.

Comment: `b.delivered = 'true'` in not exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `group by` with `having` as follows:

```
select a.column_id, a.column_name 
  from a join b on a.column_id = b.tablea_id
group by a.column_id, a.column_name
having count( b.delivered <> 'true' ) = 0;
```

Comment: You want `SUM(b.delivered <> 'true')`, to add up all true = 1 (thus not counting false = 0). If you use `COUNT`, then you count both true = 1 and false = 0, because `COUNT` counts all non-null values. (And if the column `delivered` is a boolean and not a string, then this becomes `SUM(b.delivered)` of course.)